# Selection of Selector to Change Font

Tags: css

I'm tring to change the font of my Add to Cart button (green one) on this URL, but I can"t make it

I've tried pretty much each selector, even added the !important, but nothing to do, I don't understand why...

Any idea?

The URL: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/boucles-oreilles/products/boucles-oreilles-case-africaine?variant=6090703339550

I cannot control the HTML

Here is the code:

```
span#AddToCartText, .header-cart .cart_button_secure span, #AddToCart, #AddToCartText, .productInfo form .button, .add_to_cart_btn.button, span#AddToCartText add_to_cart_txt_243881705502 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

Let me know, thanks :)
Pascal

Comment: Your HTML should be within the question too, not as an external link. Read [ask] if you need more info.

Comment: Btw, space is not valid in an `id`

Comment: Hey I do not control the HTML unfortunately
And I don't control space within the id, since I haven't built the theme

Comment: Add that to the question...and the code, as whether you can control it or not, it should be within it and not just an external link. Read how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id contains spaces which a bit inconvenient:

```
<span id="AddToCartText add_to_cart_txt_445201055774">Ajouter au Panier</span>
```

You can use

```
span[id='AddToCartText add_to_cart_txt_445201055774'] {
  font-family: "Montserrat", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
```

I just tried  `document.querySelector("[id='AddToCartText add_to_cart_txt_445201055774']")` and it works.

Comment: Hey thank you for quicky reply, sorry if I wasn't clear but I'd like ALL my ATC buttons to be Montserrat, so the code with the numbers won't work

Comment: Just to let you know guys, I have asked my theme developer about that and he will look into.
Reason I got this issue is that he put dynamic IDs regarding an update, but it should be possible to play with the selectors soon.
Thank you for the time spent :)